# apt-get packages automatically installed (by what?!) and can be removed (but I need them!)

Tags: installation, apt, wine, package-management, dependencies

apt-get is prompting me to remove these packages since they were automatically installed but are no longer required:

```
libcapi20-3 libgif4:i386 libnss-winbind libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libpam-winbind ttf-droid ttf-liberation ttf-umefont ttf-unfonts-core winbind wine wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386 wine1.4 wine1.4-amd64 wine1.4-i386:i386 winetricks
```

I'm not sure, but wine was installed as a playonlinux dependency. I'm obviously using playonlinux and it is currently installed, so either playonlinux package has messed up dependencies or something else happened.

I could quickly mark wine as manually installed, so apt won't ask me to delete it, but I want to know *which packages* are no longer requiring these dependencies.

Is there any satanic ritual I can use to achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Search for 'apt rdepends' or 'aptitude why' and it will tell you. I am not providing an answer because I am sure there is a duplicate question for this.

Comment: Many thanks and sorry for the duplicate question!